# Sorting Multi-Index to full depth (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which Im loading from a csv file and then setting the index to few of its columns (usually two or three) by the `set_index` method. The idea is to then access parts of the dataframe using several key combination, as such:

```
df.set_index(['fileName','phrase'])
df.ix['somePath','somePhrase']
```

Apparently, this type of selection with multiple keys is only possible if the `MultiIndex` of the dataframe is sorted to sufficient depth. In this case, since im supplying two keys, the `.ix` operation will not fail only if the dataframe `MultiIndex` is sorted to depth of at least 2.

for some reason, when Im setting the index as shown, while to me it seems both layers are sorted, calling  `df.index.lexsort_depth` command returns `1` , and I get the following error when trying to access with two keys:

> MultiIndex lexsort depth 1, key was length 2

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are asking. Multi-index docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)

The OP needs to set the index, then sort in place

```
df.set_index(['fileName','phrase'],inplace=True)
df.sortlevel(inplace=True)
```

Then access these levels via a tuple to get a specific result

```
df.ix[('somePath','somePhrase')]
```

Maybe just give a toy example like this and show I want to get a specific result.

```
In [1]: arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'])
   ...:    .....: ,
   ...:    .....:           np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])
   ...:    .....:           ]

In [2]: df = DataFrame(randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                0         1         2         3
bar one  1.654436  0.184326 -2.337694  0.625120
    two  0.308995  1.219156 -0.906315  1.555925
baz one -0.180826 -1.951569  1.617950 -1.401658
    two  0.399151 -1.305852  1.530370 -0.132802
foo one  1.097562  0.097126  0.387418  0.106769
    two  0.465681  0.270120 -0.387639 -0.142705
qux one -0.656487 -0.154881  0.495044 -1.380583
    two  0.274045 -0.070566  1.274355  1.172247

In [4]: df.index.lexsort_depth
Out[4]: 2

In [5]: df.ix[('foo','one')]
Out[5]: 
0    1.097562
1    0.097126
2    0.387418
3    0.106769
Name: (foo, one), dtype: float64

In [6]: df.ix['foo']
Out[6]: 
            0         1         2         3
one  1.097562  0.097126  0.387418  0.106769
two  0.465681  0.270120 -0.387639 -0.142705

In [7]: df.ix[['foo']]
Out[7]: 
                0         1         2         3
foo one  1.097562  0.097126  0.387418  0.106769
    two  0.465681  0.270120 -0.387639 -0.142705

In [8]: df.sortlevel(level=1)
Out[8]: 
                0         1         2         3
bar one  1.654436  0.184326 -2.337694  0.625120
baz one -0.180826 -1.951569  1.617950 -1.401658
foo one  1.097562  0.097126  0.387418  0.106769
qux one -0.656487 -0.154881  0.495044 -1.380583
bar two  0.308995  1.219156 -0.906315  1.555925
baz two  0.399151 -1.305852  1.530370 -0.132802
foo two  0.465681  0.270120 -0.387639 -0.142705
qux two  0.274045 -0.070566  1.274355  1.172247

In [10]: df.sortlevel(level=1).index.lexsort_depth
Out[10]: 0
```

Comment: I thought i was clear. I saw the doc you linked to already, it didnt help. the problem starts when you try to acess a specific row with it's key. If the index is not sorted by all levels, you get an error. question is how to sort the index in all levels

Comment: just ``df.sortlevel()``

Comment: I did, it is not working properly. when I sortlevel by 'fileName', the outer index get sorted, an the inner ('phrase') get mixed. when i sortlevel by 'phrase' the outerlevel ('fileName') get mixed, while the inner level get sorted. In both cases the depth of sorting is 1, which prevents me from accessing the df with two keys. I need some way to sort the outer index and **then** sort the inner index without changing the order of the outer index. i.e. - I need two layers of sort.

Comment: you'll have to show a complete example which fails; ``sortlevel`` sorts by the level and then subsequent levels

Comment: You are right. after running sortlevel it did sort all the way. I think when I tried it the first time, I forgot the inplace flag. the  Only thing I dont understand is why after the call to `set_index()` the levels were not sorted to full depth immidiatly.

Comment: Jeff, edit you answer to fit the edited question an I'll except it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ``set_index`` does not sort, as it can in theory be an expensive operation. that's why some of this is currently 'manual'.

Comment: For those Reading recently:  this deprecated since 0.20, use `sort_index` instead

Answer (score 4):

I realize some time has passed but I seem to have had the same problem as @idoda did, with the accepted answer not working on MultiIndex dataframes when the dataframes may have multiple indexes on both the columns and index. The trick, not currently shown here, is that there is an "axis" option which defaults to zero but can also be set to 1.

For example if you try:

```
df.sortlevel(inplace=True,sort_remaining=True)
```

And are still getting lexsort errors it may be relevant to know that their is a default "axis=0" kwarg in there. Thus you can also try adding

```
df.sortlevel(axis=1,inplace=True,sort_remaining=True)
```

Which should sort the other direction. If you don't want to think about it, you can just brute force it with:

```
df.sortlevel(axis=0,inplace=True,sort_remaining=True)
df.sortlevel(axis=1,inplace=True,sort_remaining=True)
```

That should fully sort both columns and row indexes at all levels. I had the same problem here and couldn't get a full lexsort with the suggested answer but a bit of research showed that even with "sort_remaining" True the sortlevel applies to only a single axis. These snippets are the solution to that which appear to be the current pythonic native answer. Hope somebody finds it helpful!

Comment: sortlevel is deprecated - is there a way to do this with sort_index?

Answer (score 3):

Pandas provides:

```
d = d.sort_index()
print d.index.is_lexsorted() # Sometimes true
```

which will do what you want in most cases.
However, always sort the index, but may be leave it 'lexsorted' (for example, if you have NANs in the index), which [generates a PerformanceWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860117/why-performancewarning-when-indexed-lookup-on-sorted-index).

To avoid this:

```
d = d.sort_index(level=d.index.names)
print d.index.is_lexsorted() #  true
```

... though why there's a difference doesn't seem to be documented.