# What exactly is the lexsort_depth of a multi-index Dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What exactly is the `lexsort_depth` of a multi-index dataframe? Why does it have to be sorted for indexing?

For example, I have noticed that, after manually building a multi-index dataframe `df` with columns organized in three levels, if I try to do:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df[idx['foo', 'bar']]
```

I get:

```
KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'
```

and at this point, `df.columns.lexsort_depth` is `0`

**However,** if I do, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981518/sorting-multi-index-to-full-depth-pandas) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/x5vHWNkhVeM):

```
df = df.sortlevel(0,axis=1)
```

then the cross-section indexing works. Why? What exactly is `lexsort_depth`, and why sorting with `sortlevel` fixes this type of indexing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*lexsort_depth* is the number of levels of a multi-index that are sorted lexically. That is, in an a-b-c-1-2-3 order (normal sort order).

So element indexing *will* work if a multi-index is not sorted, but the lookups may be quite a bit slower (in 0.15.2, this will show a `PerformanceWarning` for doing these kinds of lookups, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html)

The reason that sorting in general a good idea is that pandas is able to use hash-based indexing to figure out where the location is in a particular level independently for the level. ; then you can use these indexers to find the final locations.

Pandas takes advantage of `np.searchsorted` to find these locations when its sorted. If its not sorted, then you have to fallback to some different (slower) methods.

[here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/index.py#L4269) is the code that does this.