# How to maintain lexsort status when adding to a multi-indexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, functional-programming

Say I construct a dataframe with pandas, having multi-indexed columns:

```
mi      = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['trial_1', 'trial_2', 'trial_3'], ['motor_neuron','afferent_neuron','interneuron'], ['time','voltage','calcium']])
ind     = np.arange(1,11)
df      = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,27),index=ind, columns=mi)
```

[Link to image of output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVi0Z.png)

Say I want only the voltage data from trial 1. I know that the following code fails, because the indices are not sorted lexically:

```
idx    = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:,idx['trial_1',:,'voltage']]
```

As explained [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116739/what-exactly-is-the-lexsort-depth-of-a-multi-index-dataframe), the solution is to sort the dataframe's indices, which works as expected:

```
dfSorted    = df.sortlevel(axis=1)
dfSorted.loc[:,idx['trial_1',:,'voltage']]
```

I understand why this is necessary. However, say I want to add a new column:

```
dfSorted.loc[:,('trial_1','interneuron','scaledTime')] = 100 * dfSorted.loc[:,('trial_1','interneuron','time')]
```

Now `dfSorted` is not sorted anymore, since the new column was tacked onto the end, rather than snuggled into order. Again, I have to call `sortlevel` before selecting multiple columns.

I feel this makes for repetitive, bug-prone code, especially when adding lots of columns to the much bigger dataframe in my own project. Is there a (preferably clean-looking) way of inserting new columns in lexical order without having to call sortlevel over and over again?

Comment: It's a good question and I don't have an answer, but maybe panel (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel)  or xarray (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) would be an option instead of multiindex?

Comment: In the example I included here, a panel or xarray would work because the multi-index structure is the same for all indices. But in my actual project, some indices have completely different sets of sub-indices, so I cannot use panel or xarray.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `filter` which does a text filter on the column names:

```
In [117]: df['trial_1'].filter(like='voltage')
Out[117]:
   motor_neuron afferent_neuron interneuron
        voltage         voltage     voltage
1     -0.548699        0.986121   -1.339783
2     -1.320589       -0.509410   -0.529686
```

Comment: I see how your code returns a portion of a multi-indexed table. But I don't see how it can be used to insert a new column and maintain lexsort status.

Comment: i don't think you need to worry about lexsort anymore if you're not using `loc` to index. just add your extra columns like `df[('trial_1','interneuron','scaledtime')] = 100 * df[('trial_1','interneuron','time')]` and the filter should still work

Comment: Let me make sure I understand correctly: filter is a workaround that doesn't care whether the dataframe is sorted. Meanwhile, indexing requires a sorted dataframe. If this is right, then filter might take longer to compute, because it has to traverse the index hierarchy each time. Indexing is in general faster, but it comes with the requirement that you sort your table after each edit.

Comment: Yes you're right that in general a lookup in a sorted index will be quicker than a general hashtable, however you can still use the `filter` concept, except you would use `Series.searchsorted`. I would definately skip sorting If it's not a performance bottleneck for you, I much prefer the clearer code