# Why do i get an error whilst slicing using df_grouped.loc[ ] after grouping a few columns from df?

Tags: python

I am a SAS user. Playing around with some data manipulation in Python

```
isc_summary_sales=isc.groupby(['country','sales_channel','item_type'],as_index=False).aggregate({'order_id':['count'],'units_sold':['sum'],'unit_cost':['mean'],'unit_price':['mean'],'total_cost':['sum'])
```

The above code works just fine, but on trying to slice, lets say

```
isc_summary_sales.loc[:,'country':'total_cost']
```

I get an error

```
UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (1) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'
```

However with `isc_summary_sales.iloc[:,0:7]` it works fine.

I don't understand what this means. Why does it occur?

Comment: are you trying to select only columns "country" and "total_cost", or all the columns between them?

Comment: between them is what i want..works with iloc but not with loc

Answer (score 2):

The reason it throws that error is because after you aggregate you have 2 level indexing for your columns.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2], "b":[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4], "c":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], "d":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]})
df_summary = df.groupby(["a", "b"], as_index=False).aggregate({"c":["mean", "sum"], "d":['sum']})
print(df_summary)

   a  b    c       d
        mean sum sum
0  1  1  1.5   3   3
1  1  3  3.0   3   3
2  2  1  1.0   1   1
3  2  4  4.0   4   4
4  3  2  2.0   2   2
```

As you can see now you no longer have the simple columns "a", "b", "c" and "d", but instead you have multilevel columns. It seems like method "loc" requires that our DataFrame is lexically sorted, and when we aggregated the original DataFrame we created new columns that are no longer sorted. We can however sort them again with:

```
df_summary = df_summary.sortlevel(0, axis=1)

# And now this works
print(df_summary.loc[:, "b" : "d"])
   b    c       d
     mean sum sum
0  1  1.5   3   3
1  3  3.0   3   3
2  1  1.0   1   1
3  4  4.0   4   4
4  2  2.0   2   2
```

You may also want to reduce by one level the columns. I can do this with:

```
df_summary.columns = ['_'.join(col[0] if col[1] == '' else col) for col in df_summary.columns]

# Which makes my DataFrame look like this
print(df_summary)
   a  b  c_mean  c_sum  d_sum
0  1  1     1.5      3      3
1  1  3     3.0      3      3
2  2  1     1.0      1      1
3  2  4     4.0      4      4
4  3  2     2.0      2      2
```

More informaton about MultiLevel indexing can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: also this question may explain more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116739/what-exactly-is-the-lexsort-depth-of-a-multi-index-dataframe

Comment: Thank You so much. Detailed & helpful. The snipets make it super clear. Cheers :)