# Why PerformanceWarning when indexed lookup on sorted index?

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know why this gives a PerformanceWarning?

```
d=pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [1,2,4],
        [1,None,5],
        [2,3,5],
    ],
    columns=['i','j','k']
)
print d.dtypes
d = d.set_index(['i','j'])['k']
d = d.sort_index()

print d.loc[(2,3)] #  PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
```

My understanding from the docs is that the PerformanceWarning follows from not sorting the index (the index was sorted).

Comment: I think you missed the part of question. Please confirm it.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you

Comment: That `None` is throwing it off.  I'm fairly sure that there is a sortedness check that occurs and it is failing when there is a missing value in the index.

Comment: It doesn't give the warning if you explicitly use `d = d.sort_index(level=[0, 1])` and `d.index.lexsort_depth` returns 2 instead of 1 in that case. I am not sure what the default behavior is when `level=None` but it seems it checks whether the index is already sorted somewhere.

Comment: @ayhan -- Yes, it seems so. However, its a little odd that  `sort_index(level=..all levels...)`  doesn't have the same effect as `sort_index()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is an open bug:

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19771
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17931

@ayhan's comment provides workaround:

```
d = d.sort_index(level=d.index.names)
```

which is should be the default behavior of:

```
d = d.sort_index()
```